# Can I return structure as field initializers in C#?

Tags: c#

Ni hao ma, stackoverflow!
Imagine if I have structure like this in **C++**:

```
strcut rectangle_t
{
  std::size_t width;
  std::size_t height;
  double x;
  double y;
};
```

So in the same language I can have a function with this type that will return field initializers but not the object created before

```
rectangle_t someRect()
{
  return {5, 6, 7.0, 8.0};
}
```

Seems that I can't do the same thing in **C#**, this code:

```
using System;

namespace MyConsoleApplication
 {
    struct rectangle_t
    {
        public uint width;
        public uint height;
        public double x;
        public double y;
    }
    class PublicStaticVoidMain
    {
        rectangle_t someRect()
        {
            return {5, 6, 7.0, 8.0};
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            rectangle_t rect;
            rect.width = 1;
            System.Console.WriteLine("$1", rect.width);
        }
    }
 }
```

Is not compiled due to these errors:

```
hello.cs(16,11): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '{'
hello.cs(16,12): error CS1002: ; expected
hello.cs(16,13): error CS1002: ; expected
hello.cs(16,13): error CS1525: Invalid expression term ','
hello.cs(16,15): error CS1002: ; expected
hello.cs(16,16): error CS1002: ; expected
hello.cs(16,16): error CS1525: Invalid expression term ','
hello.cs(16,18): error CS1002: ; expected
hello.cs(16,21): error CS1002: ; expected
hello.cs(16,21): error CS1525: Invalid expression term ','
hello.cs(16,23): error CS1002: ; expected
hello.cs(16,26): error CS1002: ; expected
```

So, if you are still reading this, thank you in advance but could you also, please, tell me how should I act in this situation? I should return an instance of rectangle_t object instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# code is a bit wordier:

```
rectangle_t someRect()
{
    return new rectangle_t { width = 5, height = 6, x = 7.0, y = 8.0 };
}
```

On the other hand, anyone reading it doesn't have to memorize whether the corner coordinates or size comes first.

In newer versions of C#, you might prefer to replace the definition of `struct rectangle_t` by just

```
using rectangle_t = (uint width, uint height, double x, double y);
```

and then you can use tuple syntax:

```
rectangle_t someRect()
{
    return (5, 6, 7.0, 8.0);
}
```

But this doesn't give you an actual type named `rectangle_t`, it's just a compile-time alias.

Comment: And it will not break code if the order of Fields ever changes :)

Comment: Much obliged! That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force all instances of `rectangle_t` to *have to have* these values you should use a constructor:

```
public rectangle_t(uint width, uint height, double x, double y)
{
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Then in your method you can do this:

```
rectangle_t someRect()
{
    return new rectangle_t(5, 6, 7.0, 8.0);
}
```

I would also suggest looking into properties, access modifiers and naming/casing conventions of the language.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good solution too but I use structures instead of classes if that's only a filed container, so I needed something different.

Comment: @MaxVlasov: This works with a `struct` as well.  The only restriction is that a `struct` will always have a zero-argument constructor that zeroes all fields (not user-replaceable).  But constructors with one or more arguments are allowed.

Comment: @BenVoigt yeah, I undestood that it is for structure as it's simillar with class in some ways. Thank you for details about zero-constructor. That's what I really haven't know until now. I meant to say that I like to use structure when I don't need methods, as value container (Pascal shool, you know) :-)